# Is there a trick to the Steamworks minigame in Iceborne?

Tags: monster-hunter-world, monster-hunter-world-iceborne

In Seliana, it's possible to play a minigame at the Steamworks facility in which you have to guess the correct sequence of 3 button presses, which seems to be completely random. Is there a trick to successfully completing the minigame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no trick to it. The order is completely random. Also you can never "complete" the mini game for real. Once you filled up the gauge 3 times, the machine explodes and it all starts again.

It doesn't matter how long it takes you to get to that point as you will eventually get there. If you have a ton of fuel you just want to burn through, you can hold R2 (PS4) to autocomplete each sequence from left to right.

Also there is no real need to successfully complete every sequence, as even the lowest rewards you get for failing are useful in some way